# Help with Raspbian apt-get update - mirrordirector.raspbian.org not resolving

Tags: apt, update

I just ran a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and received error messages saying

```
Err http://mirrordirector,raspbian.org jessie InRelease
--Etc--
W: Failed to resolve....
```

and it said that some index files filed to downwload.

So just for a test I tried to ping that address and it said unknown host - 
I then pinged www.google.com and it worked fine.

I have plenty of disk space available on the SD card.  df says I am using 19% and have 22G available.  fsck throws a warning saying that to continue will cause severe damage.  So I said not to.  sudo fsck / simply said it is mounted and it cannot continue.

My question is:  Is there anything I can do on my end to make updates work?

--UPDATE:  Based on comments from the community it was determined that this was an intermittent problem.  By waiting for a while then trying again, it went though as normal.

Comment: My best advice is to try and run it again. If that doesn't work, try rebooting it. You also might want to try connecting it directly to your router with an Ethernet cable to see if that helps.

Comment: DNS is working fine.l  But I will try it again just to see if it was a temporary issue.

Comment: You were right, @anonymoose.  I tried again a few hours later and it worked fine.  Thank you.